# ADF Industries Best Practices

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

ADF Industries Best Practices  with data size wise flow time with number of records
I need an table with Industries Best Practices for each data load
for eg :
data size : 1 GB
number of records : 1 millions
what is the flow time of an pipeline

Source : SAP
Destination : SQL Synapse

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about optimizing dataflow performance, here is your documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance

I dont think there is a table with datasize and how many rows and an estimated speed and time to completion because each environment and data is structured differently.